# Reach class function in class?

Tags: c#, c++, class

I'm translating code from c++ to c#, now I got this problem so I can't reach the function I have to reach.

```
public struct TargetList_t
    {
        public float Distance;
        public float[] AimbotAngle = new float[3];
        public float[] aimbotAngle = new float[3];
        public float[] myCoords = new float[3];
        public float[] enemyCoords = new float[3];

        public TargetList_t(float[] aimbotAngle, float[] myCoords, float[] enemyCoords)
        {
            Distance = Get3dDistance(myCoords[0], myCoords[1], myCoords[3], enemyCoords[0], enemyCoords[1], enemyCoords[2]);

            AimbotAngle[0] = aimbotAngle[0];
            AimbotAngle[1] = aimbotAngle[1];
            AimbotAngle[2] = aimbotAngle[2];
        }
    };
```

this is my class.

```
TargetList_t TargList;
```

And thats how I'm trying to reach it.

Comment: do you need a call to constructor? something like `TargetList_t TargList = new TargetList_t(aimbotAngle, myCoors, ... other params);`

Comment: Side note: There's a high chance that what you want is a `class`, not a `struct`. C++'s structs are different from C#'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where in C++ you can call default constructor by

```
TargetList_t TargList;
```

In C# you always want to use a `new` keyword:

```
// init your constructor parameters
float[] aimbotAngle = new float[1]; 
float[] myCoords = new float[1]; 
float[] enemyCoords = new float[1]; 

// call constructor
var targList = new TargetList_t(aimbotAngle , myCoords , enemyCoords);
```

Notes:

- You would want to change `struct` to `class`, as this is (debatably) what it looks like
- In C++ you would add suffix or prefix, to say that it's a `type`, `int` or whatever, in C# you generally don't do that, so your class name should be `TargetList`. Further, a `List` is a well-known class in the .Net framework, so I would expect this class either to derive from it, or I would remove the List word from the name, like `TargetList_t` => `Targets`
- Instead of the public fields, use public properties

  `public float Distance;` => `public float Distance {get;set;}`

Comment: that will not work in this case. this class doesn't have a defaut constructor